# Why do I get 'ORA-12899: value too large for column' error when copying data between columns of the same type/width?

Tags: oracle, etl

I have a small java program that copies data from one database to another. Both databases have the same columns and the copy was created using the sql developer "copy database" option to create all the objects. Both databases are oracle 12.2.0 enterprise but the destination is in a docker image and will be used for development. I'm getting a weird error when copying just one table:

ORA-12899: value too large for column "MY_SCHEMA"."MY_TABLE"."MY_COLUMN" (actual: 101, maximum: 100)

Both databases have the same width on this column so not sure why its complaining.  Both are VARCHAR2(100). Maybe its something wrong with my java code? Essentially its doing this:

```
  List<Column> cols = getCols("MY_SCHEMA", "MY_TABLE",sourceConn.getMetaData());
  String sourceTableQuery = ...; //select * from my_table
  String destinationTableInsertQuery = ...;//insert into my_table(...) values(...)
  PreparedStatement queryStmt = sourceConn.prepareStatement(sourceTableQuery); 
  ResultSet data = queryStmt.executeQuery();
  PreparedStatement insertStmt = destionationConn.prepareStatement(destinationTableInsertQuery); 

  while (data.next()) {
      for(int i = 0; i < cols.size(); i++) {
         insertStmt.setObject(i+1, data.getObject(cols.get(i).getName())); 
      }
      insertStmt.addBatch();

  }
  int [] results = insertStmt.executeBatch();
```

Edit: the exact data type is VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) on both columns. Sorry if that caused any confusion.

Comment: Is it possible that one db is defined as VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) vs VARCHAR2(100)? Or that the language is different between them? The first thing that comes to mind is a issue with multibyte international characters. Or something like carriage returns on different OS.

Comment: Why not just create a database link between the two databases and then just use an SQL statement `INSERT INTO my_table (...) SELECT ... FROM my_table@source;`? Or use RMAN to backup the source and then restore it to the destination?

Comment: because I dont have DBA access on the source database and they wont give it to me. My solution mainly works with just this one hickup and it took me 1 hour to code rather than jumping through hoops with our DBAs. Also my java code has some custom filters to copy only certain data and mask certain other things like passwords , PII, PHI I dont want to give our developers.

Comment: @del that is sort of what I was thinking as well. Its actually VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) on both databases. I think the rows that fail are edge cases which are exactly 100 characters so Im also suspecting some carriage feed or something.

Comment: Please don't put answers into a question. Instead you should create a new answer to the question with the details of your solution. I have rolled back to your previous edit so you just have the question in the question but you can copy-paste your [previous text](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69480288/3) into a new answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, if you declare a column as `varchar2(100)`, you are allocating 100 bytes of storage.  Depending on the data and the database character set, 1 character may take 1 byte of storage, 2 bytes, 3 bytes, or 4 bytes.  So that `varchar2(100)` column can store somewhere between 25 and 100 characters depending on the data and database character set.

I'd wager that the database character set (`nls_characterset` in `v$nls_parameters`) is different in the two databases.  My guess is that the destination database uses a UTF-8 character set which is variable length and the source database uses a fixed width character set.  In the row that fails, there is at least one character that requires 2 bytes of storage in the UTF-8 character set and only 1 byte of storage in the source database's character set.  (Note that the trade-off is that the UTF-8 character set supports a **much** wider range of characters than the source database's character set.)

You could declare the column as `varchar2(100 CHAR)` in both databases or at least in the destination database (using character length semantics rather than byte length semantics).  That would allocate space for 100 characters regardless of the number of bytes that data requires (note that limits on the length of `varchar2` columns are still expressed in bytes so this doesn't work with, say, `varchar2(4000)` columns unless you've enabled extended string sizes).

If you have all the DDL in one place and that DDL doesn't specify character or byte semantics, you could do an

```
alter session set nls_length_semantics = CHAR
```

before running the DDL to create your objects in the source database if you don't want to go through and edit the DDL.

Comment: sorry its actually VARCHAR2(BYTE 100) on both sides. select * from v$nls_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET'; source:WE8MSWIN1252  dest:AL32UTF8 also the length_semantic is BYTE on both

Comment: If I delete 2 characters from the source before I write it to the local database the error goes away. I would prefer to fix this issue though. Do you think its worth trying to convert so local DB is the same character set? "alter database character set WE8MSWIN1252" fails with "new character set must be a superset of old character set". I am not a DBA so not sure if there is any easy way to convert the DB. I can reload all the data so not worried about data loss - just not positive the steps to follow

Comment: Updating the char set seems to have worked. Ill post the exact steps in my orginal post and accept this as the answer!

Answer (score 1):

steps to update database character set. Please dont do this without reading up as it can corrupt your database. I had to use INTERNAL_USE keyword because WE8MSWIN1252 is not a superset of AL32UTF8. I dont care because I can just reload any corrupted data in my local database.

shutdown immediate

startup restrict

alter database character set ***INTERNAL_USE*** WE8MSWIN1252;

shutdown immediate

startup